# Weird 4 tile jump height in Terraria

Tags: terraria

The problem is I have just a 4 tile jump height instead of the 6 tile in Terraria. It is really  really annoying and I don't know why did this happen. I cant find anything about it at the internet, just keep searching but I can't find anything.
Does anyone know how can i get back the 6 tile jump height? I have the game on steam, 1.3.0.8

Comment: Are you in water and trying to jump out of it?

Comment: If you hold the jump button, do you jump once and then stop, or do you keep jumping repeatedly? Former is the expected result (unless you have the Frog Leg accessory equipped).

Answer (score 5):

The game has no way to obtain a jump height of 4 blocks, you can see all the possible jump heights in the game in [this infographic from reddit user DataNalle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0fMb.png).
I would try reinstalling the game from scratch. So long as you backup your save data (located in `Documents\My Games\Terraria\` on Windows and `Library/Application Support/Terraria` on Mac.) you should be fine reinstall/verify your game.

1. Verify game cache: Right click game on library list > Properties > Local Files > Verify Integrity of Game Cache
2. Delete local content: Right click game on library list > Delete Local Content...

If none of this works and your not completely adverse to cheating you can use http://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/ to give yourself a jump boost buff/item which my help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try holding the jump, if you aren't already, as that's all i can think of and if you keep holding it as long as you can before you fall, it should go as high as you can jump.

Comment: Yep, i hold down the jump button, which is space, and the character goes up to the fourth block only. Really annoying, jsut bought a game and this happens.